# Rendering of "to fear"?

Tags: traducción, poesía

I once wrote an original poem in Spanish that includes the following:

The question relates to the second sentence, which of two translations regarding "scare me" is "better" or correct? Or can they both be used.

> Hay una cosa importante que debo decirte.
>   Aunque esta cosa siempre me da un poco miedo/me hace temor.
>   Pero si you no te digo todo sera peor,
>   Oye por favor, me grito del amor.

Translation:

> There is something important that I must tell you.
>   Although it is something that scares me half to death.
>   But if I don't tell you it will all be for the worse.
>   Listen to me please, and hear my cry of love.

Tune: You Ren Xihuan Lan (Some People Like Blue), Chinese Karaoke.

Comment: What about *me espanta*?

Comment: If your intent is to get across "scared half to death", that's really pretty scared, unless it is said jokingly. It seems like you might not want to say "un poco" in that case because that makes it seem like it's only a little scary.

Comment: @aediaλ: This is called "parallel composing," trying to write a poem half in English, half in spanish, then trying to reconcile them. And doing both to the tune of a Chinese karaoke song.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be *me da un poco de miedo* (*de* is needed) or *me causa temor*. *Temor* has better rhyme.

Other things:

*Pero si yo no te digo* => *Pero si yo no te lo digo*

*Oye, por favor, me grito del amor* => *Escucha, por favor, mi grito de amor*

Answer (score 2):

> There is something important that I must tell you.
>   Although it is something that scares me half to death.
>   But if I don't tell you it will all be for the worse,
>   Listen to me please, and hear my cry of love.
>
> Hay algo importante que debo decirte.
>   Aunque esto me provoca mucho miedo
>   /*Pero si no te lo digo*/ Pero si no lo hago, todo será peor.
>   Escúchame por favor, y escucha mi grito de amor.

Listen,hear = escuchar
to fear=tener miedo

**Yo** tengo miedo

**Tu** tienes miedo

**El/Ella** tiene miedo

**Nosotros** tenemos miedo

**Ustedes(Vosotros)** tienen miedo

**Ellos/Ellas** tienen miedo